# Entity Framework many to many relationship add/update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I have two entities, and when I update or add only one all is ok

```
        db.Entry(user1).State = EntityState.Modified;
        foreach (var userAudio in user1.Audios)
        {
            db.Audios.AddOrUpdate(userAudio);
        }
        db.Users.AddOrUpdate(user1);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

But if I try add/update few entities:

```
        db.Entry(user1).State = EntityState.Modified;
        foreach (var userAudio in user1.Audios)
        {
            db.Audios.AddOrUpdate(userAudio);
        }
        db.Users.AddOrUpdate(user1);
        db.Entry(user2).State = EntityState.Modified;
        foreach (var userAudio in user2.Audios)
        {
            db.Audios.AddOrUpdate(userAudio);
        }
        db.Users.AddOrUpdate(user2);
        db.SaveChanges();
```

It is throwing exception:

> Attaching an entity of type 'EfTest.Entities.Audio' failed because
>   another entity of the same type already has the same primary key
>   value...

Maybe it is because I have same audios in user1 and user2, and EF can't insert them...Anyone have ideas how to get round this? thanks!

**Entities**

```
namespace EfTest.Entities
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<Audio> Audios { get; set; }
    }
    public class Audio
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Antonio it not works =(

Comment: and if you change    public List<Audio> Audios { get; set; }  to public ICollection<Audio> Audios {get;set;} and the same in ICollection<User>Users {get;set;}?? and to update db.Entry(user).CurrentValues.SetValues(usermodified);

Comment: @Antonio Anyway I think that problem in same audios, because if I delete them, all works correctly

Comment: After every     db.Users.AddOrUpdate(); use   db.SaveChanges();

Comment: @AnilPanwar not work (

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I see only one way to solve this. It is adding entities independently and then adding relations:

```
var userAudios = new List<Audio>();
// Key userId
// Value list of audiosIds
var userAudiosRelations = new List<Relation>();
foreach (var user in users)
{

    foreach (var audio in user.Audios)
    {
        if (!userAudios.Any(x => x.Id == audio.Id))
        {
            userAudios.Add(audio);
        }
        userAudiosRelations.Add(new Relation
        {
            User_Id = user.Id,
            Audio_Id = audio.Id
        });
    }
    user.Audios = null;
    db.Users.AddOrUpdate(user);
}
foreach (var audio in userAudios)
{
    db.Audios.AddOrUpdate(audio);
}
db.SaveChanges();

var existingRelations = db.Database.SqlQuery<Relation>("SELECT * FROM dbo.UserAudios").ToList();
var relationsToAdd =
    userAudiosRelations.Where(
        x => existingRelations.All(y => x.User_Id != y.User_Id || x.Audio_Id != y.Audio_Id)).ToList();

foreach (var relation in relationsToAdd)
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.UserAudios (User_Id, Audio_Id) VALUES (@p0, @p1)",
        relation.User_Id, relation.Audio_Id);
}
```

Where relation model:

```
public class Relation
{
    public int User_Id { get; set; }
    public int Audio_Id { get; set; }
}
```